# Circle collision in JavaScript

Tags: javascript, detection, geometry

For school I need to make a program in JavaScript that says if circles had a collision.

It doesn't need to be shown graphically.

I gave it a try, but my code doesn't seem to work. How can I fix it?

Here's the code I produced:

```
function collision (p1x, p1y, r1, p2x, p2y, r2) {
    var a;
    var x;
    var y;

    a = r1 + r2;
    x = p1x - p2x;
    y = p1y - p2y;

    if (a > (x*x) + (y*y)) {
        return true;
    } else {
        return false;
    }
}
var collision = collision(5, 500, 10, 1000, 1500, 1500);
alert(collision);
```

Comment: Aren't you missing something in your formulae here?

Comment: And you can change your return statement to just `return (a > (x*x) + (y*y));` Rather than using an if to return true or false, since that's what the condition already is.  Or better, store the condition in a variable named `var isCollision = (a > (x*x) + (y*y));` and `return isCollision;`  It just makes it easier to read.  And don't reuse variable names like collision for two things.

Comment: Reread the distance forumula. You've almost got it, but there's a part missing.

Comment: A good way to debug issues is to step through the code.

Answer (score 12, accepted):

Your check should be `if (a > Math.sqrt((x*x) + (y*y)))`
http://cgp.wikidot.com/circle-to-circle-collision-detection

So the complete code is

```js
function collision(p1x, p1y, r1, p2x, p2y, r2) {
  var a;
  var x;
  var y;

  a = r1 + r2;
  x = p1x - p2x;
  y = p1y - p2y;

  if (a > Math.sqrt((x * x) + (y * y))) {
    return true;
  } else {
    return false;
  }
}
var collision = collision(5, 500, 10, 1000, 1500, 1500);
console.log(collision);
```

---

and for a less computational implementation (*using ES7 syntax for the snippet*) use

```js
const checkCollision = (p1x, p1y, r1, p2x, p2y, r2) => ((r1 + r2) ** 2 > (p1x - p2x) ** 2 + (p1y - p2y) ** 2)

var collision = checkCollision(5, 500, 10, 1000, 1500, 1500);
console.log(collision);
```

as Darek Rossman shows in [his answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8331243/circle-collision-in-javascript/8331460#8331460).

Answer (score 3):

In your *if* statement, try this instead:

```
if ( a * a > (x * x + y * y) ) {
    ...
} else {
    ...
}
```

Answer (score 0):

The length of a triangle having sides `dx` and `dy` (i.e. the distance between points `(x1, y1)` and `(x2, y2)` where `dx = x2 - x1` and `dy = y2 - y1`) is equal to:

```
sqrt(dx^2 + dy^2)
```

So you probably want:

```
if(a > Math.sqrt(x*x + y*y)) {
```